# How to use sum() with join and group by statement

Tags: laravel-5, sum

I want to sum of amount by currency wise

I do in SQL like this

```
select sum(total),currencies.currency_symbol from invoices
join(currencies)
where(invoices.currency_id = currencies.id)
group by(currency_id)
```

I tried in Laravel like this

```
$sum = Invoice::sum('total')
              ->select('currency_symbol')
              ->join('currencies','invoices.currency_id','=','currencies.id')
              ->groupBy('currency_id');
return response()->json($sum);
```

But it throws an error

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function `select()` on string

please give me solution

Comment: try to add the sum() to the end not the beginning. Your error indicates that you already calculated the sum before you are trying the select()

Comment: Have you even tried checking what `Invoice::sum` returns?

Comment: which laravel version are you using?

Comment: I use laravel 5.8

Comment: I tried Invoice::sum but it returns sum of total column but i want sum as currency wise

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use selectRaw, because the combination of sum and select i don't think will work, you can use one of the two. You might try something like this:

```
$sum = Invoice::selectRaw('currency_symbol, sum(total) as sum')
              ->join('currencies','invoices.currency_id','=','currencies.id')
              ->groupBy('currency_id');
return response()->json($sum);
```